# django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, django

Getting the above mentioned error while running a django web app which requires creating a database in sql server. I am running my code on UBUNTU 18.04 LTS HOSTED ON A Windows 10 computer.

My base.py file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'HOST':'localhost,1433', ## to be used in Linux OS
        'NAME':'dbname',
        'USER':'sa',
        'PASSWORD':'#######',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
            'host_is_server': True,
            },
        }
    }

quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus('driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};server=localhost,1433;database=dbname;UID=sa;PWD=#######;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes;Connection Timeout=30;')
```

My SQL Server consists of the following:
*1. An initial login by the name of 'sa'
2. A DB by the name of 'dbname'*
My Django version: 3.0.6
My Python version: 3.6.9

Please ley me know if more info is required. Very naive to coding!

Comment: I suggest creating a separate `LOGIN` (and `USER`s) instead of using the `sa` account for your application. The `sa` can literally do *anything* on the server, and an application should not have that type of permissions unless it really needs to (I doubt a python application does). Normally that's limited to applications that provide high quality maintenance tasks.

Comment: were you able to solve the problem? I have the same problem and can't solve it